# How to analyze ordinal repeated measures data

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-data, sas, ordinal-data, crossover-study

I have data from an ordinal scale, with the score ranging from 1-4.  Each subject has 9 assessments on this scale (study is a 9-way crossover design), and there are no missing data.  What is the proper statistical analysis for ordinal data that also can account for the correlation within subjects?  SAS is the preferred software for analysis, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing SAS might have a multilevel ordinal modelling facility.  You'd just specify the subject variable as a random effect.  If it's not available in SAS you could try the ordinal package in R and the `clmm` function.

Comment: Further question- Would proc genmod or glimmix work?

Comment: GENMOD with the repeated option sounds good.